# onclick firing on page load, need to call function with parameters

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this may be deemed a slight duplicate, however I couldn't find an answer that helped me understand why `myFunc()` is firing on page load and not when I click `el1` or `el2`.  How can I make the following code behave as expected?

```
function myFunc(param){
    //yadayada
}

el1.onclick = myFunc('string1');
el2.onclick = myFunc('string2');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('el1').onclick = function() { myFunc('string1'); };
document.getElementById('el2').onclick = function() { myFunc('string2'); };
```

You need to get the elements on the page first and then assign a function to them, otherwise the parser will execute them onload because it thinks that `myFunc()` is returning a value to be assigned to `onclick` as opposed to the actual function `myFunc()`.

Comment: Its semi-pseudo, I was trying to give the impression that I'd already stored the elements in the respective variables. edit, the edit makes more sense

Comment: I just updated my explanation in my answer.  Hopefully that is a little bit clearer.

Comment: yeah thanks for clearing that up for me, its obvious when its explained to you, I should of thought :)